# Kindly solve this question from coordinate geometry.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

The co-ordinates of a point P referred to a rectangular co-ordinate system where O is the origin are $(1,-2)$. The axes are rotated about 0 through angle theta, if coordinates of the new P are $(k-1,k+1)$, then $k^2$?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What tools can you use?

Comment: well i tried rotating the axes, the answer doesn't seem to match, i think it is something related to rectangular axes. And Btw, the answer is 3/2.

Comment: If you rotate the axis, does it change the lenght of the vector?

Comment: with respect to a point, yes i suppose.

Comment: With respect to the origin.

Comment: Have you got any ideas?

Comment: I am telling you my idea. Under a rotation with respect to the origin the length of the vector doesn't change. So the length of $(1,-2)$ is the same as the lenth of $(k-1,k+1).$

Comment: Wow, thanks there. It worked!

Comment: You're welcome. It was a pleasure. And, please, for further questions write your work/ideas in the body question.

Comment: Sure I will, much appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rotations preserve length and because it's a rotation with respect to the orgin, the distance from $(1,-2)$ to the orgin is equal to the distance from $(k-1, k+1)$ to the orgin. We can write the equation $$\sqrt{1^2+(-2)^2}=\sqrt{(k-1)^2+(k+1)^2}.$$
Squaring both sides and expanding gives us $$5=2k^2+2.$$
Thus, $$2k^2=3$$ and $$\boxed{k^2=\frac{3}{2}}.$$

Comment: Thanks, btw if rotation is not with respect to the origin, will the length still be constant?

Comment: Nope, the distance to the orgin will not be constant if it's rotated with respect to any other point.

Comment: I understand that the distance to the origin to the origin won't be constant as such, but i meant to ask about the 'vector length'